# Datastructure to represent hierarchial structure

Tags: c++, data-structures

I recently had an interview question that asked how to represent an organizational structure with data structures. Queries like list all employees under a manager should be efficiently queried.

I was answering on the lines of a N-way tree, though I was not very sure what should be the key and how to implement it. Curious to know what is the best way this can be done.

Comment: There are lots of ways to represent hierarchies/trees, depending on the environment. A bunch of database tables representing one-to-many relations only might be best in some settings, pointer trees in others.

Comment: how can facts like these be represented. Employees->managers->business heads->VP->President->CEO

Answer (score 1):

An oriented graph with [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) representation seems to be the best solution.

Comment: isn't it always going to be a tree (no cycles)

Comment: Well, not really. It can be a DAG(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) as well if we allow a person to have more then one boss.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a choice - custom containers that are slightly more efficient for this exact need, or working out which STL containers are going to do a pretty good job.  In an interview, I'd definitely start by saying - "let's explore what the STL containers would do, then see if there's inefficiencies (either in scalability or in support of concurrency) justifying a custom container".

So, typically you'd have a unique employee_id for each employee.  You want to be able to search for employees using that id, and probably by name, and get reasonably fast results.  So, if you want fast arbitrary insert/delete you could use a std::map or unordered_map (C++11) of employee id to employee name and other details, and another map going from name to employee_id.  If the data doesn't change (often), either or both could be a sorted vector - a little better packed and memory/cache-efficient, but still allowing O(log2n) lookup.  Given that basic model, we can extend it to reflect the relationships between employees by having each employee object contain the employee_id of their manager, and a vector of the employee_ids of their direct reports.  As the number of direct reports is unlikely to ever be too large, a vector is quite practical.  This does mean that to list all employees you have to "walk the tree" of direct reports and their direct reports etc., but that's pretty efficient anyway and saves a lot of memory compared to redundantly recording all direct and indirect reports against every employee.

In all probability, the STL approach above will suit your needs.  With a little locking it can be thread safe albeit perhaps not optimally performant.  Still, when there is demand for more scalability, persistence, cross-process transactional semantics, etc. the data's probably better moved off into a commercial database anyway unless you're a specialist in in-memory databases (e.g. when I worked in Bloomberg's Ticker Plant - inserting hundreds of thousands of financial records per second - we did specialise, but few HR programs require it).